# Disable Console Logging from MongoDB in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, logging, mongodb-java

I'm using a Mongo Database to store information from my Java program. 
I'm using Eclipse and MongoDB 3.0
The problem I am having is that whenever my program has any interaction with Mongo it fills the console with red text from JULLogger.

I do not currently have any code to set the logger level, as all examples I have found on here or elsewhere online have given the error:

```
    Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
    mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE); 

   "The method getLogger(String) is undefined for the type Logger"
```

Here is the output:

```
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017],     
    mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description  
    ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, 
    type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:117}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description 
    ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, 
    state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 7]}, 
    minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null,    
    maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=587005}
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:118}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
    Document{{_id=567045259311932a6406b4e2, time=16:51:48, data=[31C, 38C, 20C]}}
    Dec 16, 2015 8:49:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:118}] to        
    127.0.0.1:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

Could anyone advise me on how to remove all the Mongo logs from my console?

Comment: What type is Logger?  Doesn't look to be the JULLogger as that has a `getLogger(String name)` method.

Comment: I'm quite new to java so you'll have to bear with me I'm afraid. I am unsure as to what type the logger is, I'm assuming that it is JULLogger as the output says "com.mongodb.diagnostics.JULLogger log"

Comment: Correct the Mongo Driver is using the `java.util.logging.Logger` - its strange that in your code you're getting that error message.   I wanted to make sure that `Logger` in your code is the correct one.  Do you get the same error with:         `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);`

Comment: I'm getting this error when using that code: "java.util.log‌​ging cannot be resolved to a variable". Just to clarify, I'm placing this code within a menu function in main(); just before I run the code with collects data from my mongoDB. Is this the correct place to put it?

Comment: @Ross I'm not sure if this will help you but here is my code and where I am placing the code you have given me [image](http://imgur.com/MdiTH8h)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you very much Ross for your suggestion:

`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.log‌​ging.Level.SEVERE);`

In fact the correct code was this, so only a minor change:

`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);`

I can confirm that I am not longer receiving any logs from mongo within the console at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution Just add following dependency in your pom file or add this jar manually

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Read these

1. http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/153eg0pczd/deactivate-logging-in-the-java-driver
2. https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping

for more and detailed explanation

I faced this similar kind of issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above but none worked.the One which finally worked is

The one which finally worked for me is as below.

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Please note the imports as well:

```
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```